# How to create downloadable URL for file that located on file system in Java?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web, server

I have local Tomcat server with Spring app.

How to create downloadable URL(for example: http://localhost:8080/file.smth) for file that located on file system(for example: C:\Files\file.smth)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring we can do this: provide GET request to obtain file from downloadble link.

```
 @RequestMapping("/models/{fileId}.smth")
        @ResponseBody
        public HttpEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable String fileId) throws IOException {
            byte[] model = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File( "C:/folder/" + fileId + ".smth"));
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            headers.setContentLength(model.length);
            return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(model, headers);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Only files below the document root configured or the web server can be accessed using an URL. (everything else would be a huge security flaw)

For files below document root remove the part of the path above and including document root, and prepend protocol and host. Replace all backslash characters with slash.

Example: your document root is `c:\www\my_site\`, and you want to create a URL for `c:\www\my_site\some\path\my_file.txt` the result would be `http://localhost:8080/some/path/my_file.txt'